# How to install Django-nonrel (Django 1.5)?

Tags: python, django, django-nonrel

How to install Django-nonrel (Django 1.5) ? Is this version of django is supported?

This is for 1.3: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/write-a-tumblelog-application-with-django-mongodb-engine/

I need >= 1.4

Comment: Use 1.4.2, its completely supported.

Comment: @Chipmunk `pip install https://github.com/django-nonrel/django-nonrel/archive/develop.zip`  is ok? This is 1.4.2?

Comment: https://github.com/django-nonrel/django-1.4

Answer (score 4):

try django-nonrel stable version

```
pip install git+https://github.com/django-nonrel/django
```

to install a specific version

```
pip install git+https://github.com/django-nonrel/django@1.5
```

Answer (score 0):

pip install git+https://github.com/django-nonrel/django@nonrel-1.5-beta works for me